# Pagination 2nd page not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Pagination works fine when I don't use the WHERE statement in my SELECT statement. For some reason as soon as I add additional requests in the SELECT statement, only the 1st pagination page works. So it seems like the variable data is lost after the first page is displayed. Below is some of the code:-

```
               <?php
                 include 'database.php';
                 include 'paginator.php';
                 $pdo = Database::connect();

                 $paginator = new Paginator();
                 $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM customer_crm ";
                 $paginator->paginate($pdo->query($sql)->fetchColumn());

                 $query =  $_GET["query"];
                 if (isset($query))  {
                   ($_GET['query'])?('%'.$_GET['query'].'%'):'%';
                   $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE firstname LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query OR telephone LIKE :query ";
                   } 
                else    {
                    $start = (($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1)*$paginator->itemsPerPage);
                    $length = ($paginator->itemsPerPage);   
                    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE customer_group_id = $input OR date_followup= CURDATE() ORDER BY customer_group_id DESC limit $start, $length ";
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit $start, $length ";
                    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE customer_group_id = $input ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit $start, $length ";
                    }


                   $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                   $sth->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                   $sth->bindParam(':length',$length,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                   $sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                   $sth->execute();



                   foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
```

Comment: What are the contents of `paginator.php`? Are we talking about CakePHP paginator or Illuminate paginator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which `Paginator` are we talking about, I could only advise you to do something like

```
include 'database.php';
include 'paginator.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$paginator = new Paginator();

$query = (isset($_GET["query"]) && strlen($_GET["query"])>1)? '%'.$_GET["query"].'%':'%';

$countsql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE firstname LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query OR telephone LIKE :query ";
$sthcount = $pdo->prepare($countsql);
$sthcount->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sthcount->execute();

$count=$sthcount->fetchColumn();
$paginator->paginate($count);

$start = (($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1)*$paginator->itemsPerPage);
$length = ($paginator->itemsPerPage); 

$sql = $countsql . ' ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit :start, :length ';

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':length',$length,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

See, you where making two mistakes here:

- getting your `count` value without considering the query. You should set the value of `$query` regardless of the existance of `$_GET['query']`, and use it in your count query as well as your results query.
- binding parameters whose placeholders and values do not exist in the query you're executing. Make sure your results query contains `:query`, `:start` and `:length` or you will be binding more parameters than the query has.

You should also have wrapped your statements in `try/catch` blocks so you could debug what was happening.

```
try {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':length',$length,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    die('Error in query: '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

That way you would have known that the query was failing because of
`Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

**NOTE** I have no clue about how your paginator will know about the current page, nor can I see where are you setting the `itemsPerPage` value.

Comment: Please ignore the $query and IF statement, as they are used purely for a search feature on the page. If there is no search request, then the ELSE query happens, which is where the pagination happens based on the SELECT request. The pagination works fine as $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit $start, $length ";, but not when I add a WHERE statement.

Comment: There is still the fact that you're binding parameters which have no placeholder in the sql sentence. You're interpolating the variables themselves in the sql directly, so there's nothing to bind. Also, use the `try/catch` block to see what's happening. Besides, when you say "it's not working" we don't understand if you mean that it shows an error, shows nothing, shows records that do not match the WHERE clause, of shows records that should be in other pages.

Comment: Not working means - Page one of paginator displays, the rest of the pages display nothing. - no error, just no result.

Comment: There's always the good ol' fashioned `die('sql is: '.$sql);` I still cannot see how paginator may know what page are you asking for. Also, are you positive that there should be more results (using your WHERE clause) than the paginator itemsPerPage?

Comment: As mentioned Paginator works with:- $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit $start, $length "; BUT NOT with:- $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE customer_group_id = $input ORDER BY date_followup DESC limit $start, $length "; SO I know that it is working, but not when I add a WHERE statement in the SELECT statement